# Is there an equivalent to FireShot for Firefox?

Tags: software-recommendation, firefox, screenshot

On windows, I can use Fireshot with FireFox to take screenshots, ufortuately, its works only on Windows... how can I do the same on Ubuntu?

The main features I will need are:

- Take full scrolling web page screenshot
- Work with Flash/Silverlight content - some screen capture will display these as black boxes or something
- If possible, have an API so I can develop scripts to make use of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Abduction](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/abduction/).

It allows you to take whole pages/selections, though I'm not sure about scripting (this should be possible though.

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do is use a Website Screenshot API from the Internet.
[ScreenshotAPI.net](https://screenshotapi.net) is such an example!