# Is there an equivalent to FireShot for Chrome

Tags: software-recommendation, google-chrome, extension, screenshot

I love FireShot but it's windows only, I do see that it comes for Chrome as well but still Windows only. Anyone found anything for Chrome on Ubuntu?

Related but still FireFox: [Is there an equivalent to FireShot for Firefox?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36551/is-there-an-equivalent-to-fireshot-for-firefox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a fair few ["Screenshot" extensions](http://goo.gl/FrAC8) for Chrome.

As you said, there is [FireShot: Quick Captures and Annotations](http://goo.gl/JIDWu) but that is Windows only.

Another alternative I have found [Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate extension](http://goo.gl/KFOi4) which seems to have reasonably high ratings and have similar functions.

FireShot's Chrome page states the following.

> ** Only 32-bit version of Google Chrome is supported**
>
> Guys, this extension currently works only for Windows platform, please do not post your reviews about unavailability of this extension for other platforms, thank you.

Their website posted this comment which unquestionably says that there will be **no** Linux support.

> Unfortunately, FireShot is and FireShot **will be available only for windows** because it's based on binaries of Screenshot Studio, which have been compiled for windows.

Comment: +1 for effort but it's not the same, Keeping the question open for now

Comment: Answer edited slightly in line with a quote I found from the FireShot team. Question should now be closed as there clearly is no alternative.

Comment: @PhillPaford: well tbh, you don't really have a choice :).

Answer (score 0):

There is famous screengrab. You have to patch the *install.rdf* file in sreengrab's xpi, which is a zip, as described [here](http://www.itsabhik.com/tech/how-to-make-screengrab-compaible-with-firefox-8.html).

This works fine for Firefox 8 on Ubuntu 11 and even on Windows 7. As compared with Firefox version 3.x (once screengrab had been developed for those versions and then stopped for some inexplicable reasons.

I tried to get its source code, however impossible so far) the only difference is that the screengrab icon won't appear in status bar after having been patched and installed. So you might make use of right mouse button to carry out any screengrab function.